# Modifying elements of Haskell 2D array

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

I am writing a function to modify elements of a given 2D "array" given below:

```
change_elem :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
-- empty list case
change_elem _ _ _ [] = []

-- have arrived at the element to change`
change_elem 0 0 x ((y:ys):ls) = (x:ys):ls

-- reduce the column until we find the element to change
change_elem 0 col x ((y:ys):ls) = [[y]] ++ change_elem 0 (col-1) x (ys:ls)

-- reduce the row until we find the column to change
change_elem row col x (l:ls) = l : change_elem (row-1) col x ls
```

It works for input such as `change_elem 1 0 3 [[1,2],[4,5]]` and produces `[[1,2],[3,5]]`.  However, my problem is when I attempt to change an element that is not in column 0, so the problem clearly lies in the "reducing column" step.

`change_elem 2 1 7 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,0]]` gives the output 
`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1],[7,0]]`.  Its behavior is that it separates the earlier elements of a given row into singleton lists.

`change_elem 0 4 10 [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]` yields `[[0],[1],[2],[3],[10,5,6]]`

Shouldn't the (++) operator return the earlier elements back into the list, leaving a single unified row?

I have tried calling concat on the resulting list, but when I modify the line to read:

```
... concat $ [[y]] ++ change_elem 0 (col-1) x (ys:ls)
```

I get a long error, but it seems like this should work.
The error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        change_elem :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
      at test.hs:15:16
Relevant bindings include
  ls :: [[a]] (bound at test.hs:23:29)
  ys :: [a] (bound at test.hs:23:25)
  y :: a (bound at test.hs:23:23)
  x :: a (bound at test.hs:23:19)
  change_elem :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
    (bound at test.hs:17:1)
In the expression: y
In the expression: [y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `++` operator does not do that.  It simply concatenates two lists together.  With `[[1]] ++ [[2]]`, you could say `x = [1]` and `y = [2]`, then you have `[x] ++ [y]`, which is clearly `[x, y]`, or `[[1], [2]]` through direct substitution.

As for solving your current problem, I would recommend writing a function that can replace an element at an index in a simple list, as in

```
replace :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace i x xs = ???
```

Then you can very simply implement `change_elem` as

```
change_elem row col x xs =
    let row_to_replace_in = xs !! row
        modified_row = replace col x row_to_replace_in
    in replace row modified_row xs
```

This is certainly not the most efficient or safest implementation, but it is a very simple one.

The reason why you're seeing that error when you use `concat` is because you're turning something of the type `[[Int]]` into `[Int]`, but you've told the compiler that your function must return something of type `[[Int]]` (when supplied with an `Int` matrix).